# WL.Analytics.log logs are not reflected in the analytics console (search tab)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

WL 6.0.0.1

I'm using the WL.Analytics.log API but no entries appear in the analytics console. (I send more than 10 logs)

I have configured in the initOptions.js the property:

```
analytics : {
    enabled: false
}
```

I have also tried with

```
WL.Analytics.enable()
```

In the worklight properties:

```
wl.analytics.logs.forward=false
wl.analytics.url=http://analytics:80/iwap/v1/events/_bulk
wl.analytics.queues=1
wl.analytics.queue.size=1
```

If I use WL.Client.logActivity it works.
If I enable wl.analytics.logs.forward I see all the server logs.
I also see the analytics sent by default when invoking an adapter, or the init event or the notifications events.

I have reviewed the analytics troubleshooting guide but I didn't find anything.

I really do not know what else to test or how to debug this.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a chance that you are sending the logs in a loop? There is a defect in which sending several logs at once causes the logs not to be sent. If this is the case, try sending them one at a time. Also, please list the device you are testing this on (Android, iOS).

Comment: Also, check to make sure you have enabled analytics as an optional feature.

Comment: Hi. I was doing it in a loop at the begining but I changed it for doing it one by one. I didn't add Analytics as an optional feature in the application... how do I add it, using the wizard does no allow me to do it, I only can add JSON. Thank you.

Comment: I'm testing in IPad2 and Samsung Galaxy S3 mini.

Comment: Hmm, then you must be using a version of Worklight that doesn't have Analytics as an optional feature. I do remember something about some analytics libraries not making it into the iPad environment for some reasons. Can you create a separate iPhone environment and run this to see if it works there? Better yet, can you try running this as 'Preview common resources' from your Worklight console and see if it sends the messages from there?

Comment: Ok... it works from the preview. iPad, Android and Common. But it does not work from the devices. Is there something I have to enable or configure like permissions?

Comment: My Worklight Studio version is 6.0.0.20130909-1459 and Server is 6.0.0.1_6.0.0.20130926_2004

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42091/discussion-between-jnortey-and-javier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with the help of support we could find the problem. It was the locale on the device.

I have changed my iPad to English (The same as workligh server and analytics server) and after rebuilding, redeploy in the stand alone worklight and reinstall in the device it worked.